# Detectar ejecutables en bash

Tags: bash, shell

Soy nuevo en el lenguaje bash (GNU/linux) y me ha surgido una duda en un ejercicio: tengo que recorrer todos los ficheros de un directorio, y para aquellos que sean ejecutables guardar en una variable un 1, o un 0 en caso de no ser ejecutable.

He probado a hacer un `if` con aquellos ficheros cuya extensión sea "*.exe", pero más tarde leí que en gnu/linux no se usan extensiones para evitar manipulaciones, sino "números mágicos". A continuación probé con el comando `file -z $nombreFichero`, pero tampoco funciona.

¿Cómo puedo detectar si el fichero es ejecutable o no? Éste es el código que llevo hasta ahora:

```
#!/bin/bash

fichero=$(mktemp)

for nombre in $(find $1 -size +$2)  
do  
   if [ -x $nombre ];  
   then  
      ejecutable=1  
   else  
      ejecutable=0  
   fi

   echo "$nombre,${#nombre},`stat -c %u $nombre`,`stat -c %U $nombre`,`stat -c %h $nombre`,`stat -c %Y $nombre`,`stat -c %A $nombre`,$ejecutable " >> $fichero
done

if [ -z "$2" ];   
then  
   for nombre in $(find $1 -size +0)  
   do  
      if [ -x $nombre ];  
      then  
         ejecutable=1  
      else  
         ejecutable=0  
      fi  
      echo "$nombre,${#nombre},`stat -c %u $nombre`,`stat -c %U $nombre`,`stat -c %h $nombre`,`stat -c %Y $nombre`,`stat -c %A $nombre`,$ejecutable" >> $fichero  
   done  
fi  

cat "$fichero" | sort -k1r  

rm "$fichero"
```

Comment: Y cómo corres ese bash? porque según veo tienes que pasarle parámetros

Comment: La clave está en la línea `[ -x $nombre ]` y es correcta. ¿Cuál es el problema que tienes con el código actual? A simple vista debería funcionar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el comando `file` que determina el tipo de archivo que se le pasa como parametro.

Ejecutándolo en un archivo de texto:

```
$ file array_string.cpp
```

> array_string.cpp: C source, ASCII text

Ejecutándolo en un archivo de ejecutable:

```
$ file array_string.exe
```

> array_string.exe: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=c1b3d0b4539fd50758195bca5b55428795fc4280, not stripped

Si se ejecuta con el parametro `-i`, te va a mostrar la información MIME ***Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions*** (o en español ***extensiones multipropósito de correo de internet***)

```
$ file -i array_string.cpp
```

> array_string.cpp: text/x-c; charset=us-ascii

```
$ file -i array_string.exe
```

> array_string.exe: application/x-executable; charset=binary

Y esta última forma de ejecución creo que te conviene más para el proposito que lo necesitas.